# Car cranks but will not start after transmission replacement

Tags: automatic-transmission, infiniti, g35

The 2006 Infiniti G35 would crank but not start after a transmission replacement.  I found 2 transmission codes.  U1000 which is a CAN bus code and P1815 which is the manual shifting code.  It is an automatic transmission with fairly low mileage.

***Does anyone know if it may need a TCM reprogram or why it doesn't start after the auto trans replacement?***

Comment: Have you checked if the crankshaft position sensor was installed and plugged in? It is located in the back on the engine underneath the car and may have been disturbed during the transmission swap.

Comment: Seems like someone should have been able to answer this one by now.   ;[

Answer (score 2):

The CANBus error is key here. Something is shorted, broken or not connected.

The suspect electrical components are:

- Manual Mode Switch Circuit
- AT Shift Selector Assembly
- Wire Harness and Connectors between components

For more diagnostic info, check out this thread:
http://www.infinitifx.org/42-2nd-gen-2009/20401-transmission-problem-different-one.html

Especially posts 8 through 11.

Comment: Nice, another unanswered question eliminated!  +1